# STM32F745VGH6 Flight Controller Circuit Design

Tags: microcontroller, stm32

I am designing a flight controller based on the STM32F745VGH6 (TFBGA100) MCU, I have a schematic based on the STM32F745VGT6 (LQFP100), and now I have a few pins that are not available in the LQFP100 package so I don't know what to do with them.
these pins are:

```
VDDUSB     Pin F6
BYPASS_REG Pin E6
PDR_ON     Pin F7
```

I think the VDDUSB  can just be simply connected to the other VDD pins, but what about the other two pins?
Should I keep them floating? or do they need special connections?

Comment: what does the datasheet say?

Answer (score 2):

You should not depend on random internet strangers for this sort of thing. A 100-ball BGA package is not easy to add fly wires to.

Read the datasheet, the [technical reference manual](https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/dm00314099-stm32h742-stm32h743-753-and-stm32h750-value-line-advanced-arm-based-32-bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf) and (particularly, in this case) the "[hardware getting started](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/application_note/b0/5c/ba/b2/cb/10/41/dd/DM00164549.pdf/files/DM00164549.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00164549.pdf)" manual.

Note: This is not a link-only answer. The links are provided, however the key point is that the information is *distributed* (potentially) in several documents with the given names, and they should be consulted and compared with requirements for the proper decisions to be made.

Comment: Just to add one more thing. There will usually be a reference design from ST which features the "largest" variant of a controller. Usually thats a pretty good reference as well.

Comment: Good point. The reference designs and demo boards can be examples of what should be (but isn't always) best practices.

Comment: Yes, I've seen my share of reference designs which contradict the instructions in the manual :-)